# How to migrate apps from windows 6.5 to Windows RT (ARM)?

Tags: windows-ce, windows-rt

I want to migrate existing working application written in Windows 6.5 phone to Windows 8 RT (ARM).

I am searching if we can do it using some tools or we have to do it manually?

Expecting links to more detailed documents and information

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's going to be a lot of work ...

Comment: while closing any question it may not be asked correctly. But the question is important for the person who has asked it. saying something incorrect about it is not the answer. Above question was really important for me. Please do not mind my words. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do it manually, there are no automated tools for it.

Win rt is light version of windows 8, so many libraries are either not available, or their references are different.